# AWK to to find first occurrence of string and assign to variable for compare

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

I have written following line of code which explodes the string by the first occurrence of the string after a delimiter.

```
echo "$line" | awk -F':' '{ st = index($0,":");print "field1: "$1 "
    =>  " substr($0,st+1)}';
```

But I don't want to display it. Want to take both occurrences in variable so I tried the following code

```
explodetext="$line" | awk -F':' '{ st = index($0,":")}';
```

Sample data:

```
id:1
url:http://test.com
```

Expected OutPUt will be:

```
key=id
val=1

key=url
val=http://test.com
```

but not working as expected.Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you want the output of your command line to be assigned to a variable in your bash script?

Comment: @ghoti: i want to assign values in variable to compare the values

Comment: What values? Your question only shows code that would produce one result, I think.  (I can't reproduce it because [you haven't included any sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, this sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Can you describe your overall goal here, rather than just ask for help implementing something that may not be the best way to achieve your goal? (Hint: add this to the question, not a comment.)

Comment: @ghoti:i have edited question to show sample data. It's simple data. I want to check if id is greater then 0 then perform action on url.

Comment: @BhumiShah : Is the data contained in a file or is it given as input when the script is run?

Comment: @sjsam: i am reading data from txt file.

Comment: The code you've written really doesn't match up at all with the expected output you've provided.  How would your output include text like `key=` and `val=` when your code does not include that text at all?

Comment: @BhumiShah : I assume your text file will contain more than one id/url pair. Am I right?

Comment: @sjsam: No,its single id and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, expanded:

```
echo "$line" \
| awk -F':' '
    {
      st = index($0,":")
      print "field1: " $1 " => " substr($0,st+1)
    }'
```

The output of this appears merely to split the line according to the first colon.  From the sample data you've provided, it seems that your lines contain two fields, which are separated by the *first* colon found.  This means you can't safely use awk's field separator to find your data (though you can use it for field names), making `index()` a reasonable approach.

One strategy might be to place your input into an array, for assessment:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=":"
}

{
  record[$1]=substr($0,index($0,":")+1);
}

END {
  if (record["id"] > 0) {
    printf("Record ID %d had a value of %s.\n", record["id"], record["url"])
  } else {
    print "No valid records found."
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see your monitor from here. What error are you seeing?

Comment: its Syntax error: "}" unexpected. when clode the first bracket and start next

Comment: It works for me. Did you copy-and-paste correctly? How are you running it? Did you save it to a file, and make that file executable, or are you trying to compose a single command line out of the code?

Comment: Yeah, file is .sh and running it from terminal. I copied your code and paste it directly. Anything i need to change?

Comment: But this code is in while loop.eg,while read line; do to read two lines of text file.

Comment: I can't see what you've done with the code. If you test it on its own, as I did, most likely it will work. If you're running the awk script once for each line of the shell scripted while loop, how will variables be held for comparison from one line to the next? You know that awk can process multiple lines, right? Are you sure you need to use a while loop? This is what I meant about the XY problem. The "right answer" to a wrong approach doesn't help you in the long run, it just accelerates you into the wall.

Comment: @ghoti: He can't use `awk's field separator to find his data` because the url may contain a colon. The substring approach may be the best here.

Comment: @ I am a novice in sh I didn't know that awk can process multiple lines  so I have used while loop but now it is solved. Actually, your code is partial so confusing. Anyway. thanks :)

Comment: @sjsam, as I mentioned in my answer, it appears that the records consist of two fields, separated by *the first colon*. This means he can use awk's field separator for easy access to `$1`, but must use something like `substr($0,index($0,":")+1)` for the second field.

Comment: I love that the OP says `your code is partial so confusing`, apparently blissfully unaware that it's 100% his XY question and lack of fundamental understanding of shell or awk that's causing all of the confusion :-).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your text file **input.txt** is stored in the format as given below:

```
id:1
url:http://test1.com
```

You could use the below piece of code, say **awkscript**, to achieve what you wish to do :

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
BEGIN{FS=":"}
{
if ($2 > 0) {
  if ( getline > 0){
  st = index($0,":")
  url = substr($0,st+1);
  system("echo Do something with " url);
  }
  }
}' $1
```

Run the code as **./awkscript input.txt**

**Note:** I assume that that the input file contains only one id/url pair as you confirmed in your comment.

Comment: you can shebang awk directly.

Comment: I see. I thought a shell script would be adequate as it could be re-used